# Cannot Set Default Geometry in Gnome Shell Terminal With .desktop File in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-shell, .desktop

I want to configure the terminal so that new windows launch on the bottom left corner of the screen. Based on [this issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48984/how-can-i-set-the-position-that-terminal-opens-at) I tried copying /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Shell.desktop to ~/.local/share/applications/ and then setting `Exec=gnome-terminal --geometry=80x24+233-58` in the .desktop file.

However, terminal windows still start at the upper left corner. I tried changing the signs on the geometry values, but the window still starts in the same place. The issue persists after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you startup the terminal. The command line options you provide will be honored only when the terminal is launched through the `.desktop` launcher. Thus, it will work if you launch the terminal from your menu.

To have it work through a shortcut, you need to adapt the command defined for the shortcut key. Alternatively, you can also have your shortcut key launch the desktop launcher with the command

```
gtk-launch org.gnome.Terminal
```

where `org.gnome.Terminal` is the name of the `.desktop` launcher without the `.desktop` extension.

Unfortunately, this cannot be set in the Profile, so limitations remain. The setting is not honored when you launch a new window from an open terminal window, or when you "Open terminal here" in the file manager.